# What's happening with the Google O3D WebGL wrapper?

Tags: html, webgl, o3d

I am not seeing any updates for  Google O3D WebGL wrapper for a very long time, and I am not seeing much in the form of posts regarding o3d webgl on this site or other content on the internet - what's happening with O3D WebGL wrapper is it still in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actively maintained inside of [`Chrome`](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/o3d/) also see [`The future of O3D`](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/05/future-of-o3d.html) blog post in Chromium blog.

Comment: When you say they are actively maintaining O3D inside the Chrome repo that sounds like they are moving the functionality that they can from the javascript library to the browser, to offset the load to the browser to handle the loading of assets more efficiently .. is that about right?

This would mean that the browser makers have decided that the browser its self needs to have a standardized WebGL wrapper built ontop of webgl no?

Still a little confused, the blog was last updated on Friday, May 07, 2010

Comment: I would say that they are going for supporting & improving WebGL. And yes, they are just making Chrome support O3D "out of the box".

Comment: Thanks for your answer İsmail, before I accept it, do think this means that working with the current javascript library would be a waste of time in your opinion? Many Thanks, Chris

Comment: Chris, I am not a JavaScript or O3D expert but as I see the recent work in Chrome I can say that 3D support in Web is going to be WebGL mostly. Checkout Google's "Body Browser", works in Chrome & Firefox. And if you add Safari to the equation then you can see its gonna be the next hit for 3D Web.